# Deleting from MySQL with Java...what's missing here?

Tags: java, mysql

A simple little function, but it generates an error.  Don't understand why when the same query works in MySQL Workbench:

```
public static String deleteDepartment(int deptId) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = getMySQLConnection();
    String query = "DELETE FROM department WHERE id = ?";

    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setInt(1, deptId);
    
    ps.executeUpdate(query);

    ps.close();
    conn.close();
    
    return "success";
}
```

The error generated is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

The query in the preparedStatement at .executeUpdate(), where 126 is a valid id:

```
DELETE FROM department WHERE id = 126
```

What am I not seeing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the wrong execute statements

use

```
ps.execute();
```

Comment: is **also** good, if we want to be correct

Comment: @isaace `executeUpdate(query)` is the wrong statement. `executeUpdate()` and `execute()` are both valid, if you don't need the update count. --- `executeUpdate()` is simply a convenience method combining `execute()` and `getUpdateCount()`.

Answer (score 4):

Found my error.  I was updating old code, replacing Statement with PreparedStatement and didn't take the query out.  The correct code is:

```
ps.executeUpdate();
```

File it under "It's been a looong day..."

Comment: too late ne ce pas